# What is the result of the US China trade war from 2018?

Tags: united-states, china, trade

Trump started a trade war with China in 2018 by imposing tariffs on a broad range of Chinese imports.

If we calculate the economic win/loss for reach side, which country lost/benefited more as of 2022: China or the USA?

Comment: Seems kind of unfair to count to 2022 instead of 2020 considering Trump wasn't president half of that time. That being said, this is not a good question because it involves hypothetical gains added with real losses. It's impossible to answer because we don't have an alternate history where the trade war didn't happen.

Comment: Surely there must be economical studies about that.

Comment: I'd be curious to know if any serious efforts to estimate this were made. I might be better to ask on https://economics.stackexchange.com/ though. With all the Covid confounders it might be too difficult tough, esp. after 2020. [According](https://www.agweb.com/news/policy/politics/who-actually-won-us-china-trade-war) to some China lost more, but I'm skeptical to put this as an answer because I don't know a lot about the credibility of those sources.

Comment: @uberhaxed Change of presidents isn't relevant here, as the new administration left the tariffs in place for now.

Comment: **We** can't calculate it.  That's outside the scope of this site.  You probably can ask a question about whether there has been such a calculation done by an authoritative 3rd party though.  So this question is salvageable, but not suitable for this site in its current form.

Comment: @wrod In principle no expert here should need to do any original research him/herself to answer a question. It's always just searching for the available facts and a bit of connecting the dots or applying a theorem. I mean we literally do not go out in the field and check that the things we say are true. That's why every answer is more or less simply a search and should be accompanied by citations. Also every question should do that already in order to show a bit of own effort and motivate why the question isn't a simple one.

Comment: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/33290/who-exactly-suffered-more-in-the-us-china-trade-war You might be interested, although there's no answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the original stated reason for the trade war was the deficit USA had in trade with China, we can evaluate the results based on [U.S. Census Bureau data](https://www.census.gov/foreign-trade/balance/c5700.html).

| Year | Balance ($bn) |
| --- | --- |
| 2017 | -375167.9 |
| 2018 | -418232.9 |
| 2019 | -342629.5 |
| 2020 | -308139.5 |
| 2021 | -353493.2 |
| 2022(Jan-May) | -163149.7 |

To clarify the last value - for the same period in 2021, the deficit amounted to roughly -$129T, i.e. we see ~1.2 increase of deficit compared to previous year.

The Chinese COVID lockdowns of 2020 noticeably impacted the balance during February-April of 2020, but the data shows that after April 2020 the values are consistent with 2019 values; I would assume the recession due to pandemic dampened the growth somewhat.

Thus, we can see that while deficit shrunk somewhat during the trade war, the deficit is increasing again since 2020, even though most tariffs are still in place. In other words, USA did not manage to meet its goal of balancing out exports with imports, and China still exports more to USA than imports from it; moreover, the trend is still in favor of China, based on first months of 2022.